# How to join maps in Apache Pig? (stored in HBase)

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I have a problem with apache pig and did not know how I can solve it, or if it is possible. Im working with hbase as the "storage layer". The table looks like this:

```
row key/column  (b1, c1)        (b2, c2)    ...     (bn, cn)
a1              empty           empty               empty   
a2              ...
an              ...
```

There are row keys a1 to an and every row has different columns with the syntax (bn, cn). The value of every row/column is empty.

My Pig Programm looks like this:

```
/* Loading the data */
mydata = load 'hbase://mytable' ... as (a:chararray, b_c:map[]);

/* finding the right elements */ 
sub1 = FILTER mydata BY a == 'a1';
sub2 = FILTER mydata BY a == 'a2');
```

Now I want to join sub1 and sub2, which means I want to find the columns that exists in both data sub1 and sub2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maps will not be able to do anything like this in pure pig.  Therefore you are going to need a UDF.  I'm not sure exactly what you want to get as output for the join, but it should be fairly easy to tweak the python UDF to your needs.

**myudf.py**

```
@outputSchema('cols: {(col:chararray)}')
def join_maps(M1, M2):
    # This literally returns all column names that exist in both maps.
    out = []
    for k,v in M1.iteritems():
        if k in M2 and v is not None and M2[k] is not None:
            out.append(k)
    return out
```

You can use it like:

```
register 'myudf.py' using jython as myudf ;

# We can call sub2 from in sub1 since it only has one row
D = FOREACH sub1 GENERATE myudf.join_maps(b_c, sub2.b_c) ;
```

Comment: I thanks. I build a MapToBag UDF in Java and that works for me. Thank you!